# Can somebody tell me what the last loop is doing ?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

```
import os
import tarfile
from six.moves import urllib
import pandas as pd
import hashlib
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, StratifiedShuffleSplit 

DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ageron/handson-ml/master/"
HOUSING_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "housing")
HOUSING_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/housing/housing.tgz"

def fetch_housing_data(housing_url=HOUSING_URL, housing_path= HOUSING_PATH):
    if not os.path.isdir(housing_path):
        os.makedirs(housing_path)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.tgz")
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(housing_url, tgz_path)
    housing_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path)
    housing_tgz.extractall(path=housing_path)
    housing_tgz.close()
#getting the housing data 


def load_housing_data(housing_path=HOUSING_PATH):
    csv_path = os.path.join(housing_path, "housing.csv")
    return pd.read_csv(csv_path)
#that function loaded the data in a panda datafrome object 


#need to call the function to get the housing data 
fetch_housing_data()
housing = load_housing_data()
housing.head()

#total bedrooms doesnt match entries deal with later 
#ocean proximity holds an object, since its in csv file still can contain text
housing.describe()
#describes the output of the housing information 


%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
housing.hist(bins=50,figsize=(20,15))
plt.show()
#creates a histogram of the data set, x axis is the range of hosuing prices, y axis number of instances of housing prices at that 
#given range 
#income data has been scaled by max 15 and .5 for lower 

#since the data of housing prices has been capped at 500k posssible delete that data set 
#thus so our model wont learn those bad values because it may not be 500k thus labels could be off 
#tail heavy because its 200K plus for example so just barel a dollar more would make it (left)

import numpy as np 

def split_train_test(data,test_ratio):
    shuffled_indices = np.random.permutation(len(data))
    #a randomized array with the same length as the input data so all data 
    test_set_size = int(len(data)*test_ratio)
    #mutliplying by a ratio to see the difference of the data 
    test_indices = shuffled_indices[:test_set_size]
    train_indices = shuffled_indices[test_set_size:]
    #taking the test of the beggining because of the entry 
    #taking rest for training 
    return data.iloc[train_indices],data.iloc[test_indices]
#redo the variable since outside the cells 
housing = load_housing_data()

#creating a category of income prices that is stratified 
housing["income_cat"] = np.ceil(housing["median_income"]/1.5)
housing["income_cat"].where(housing["income_cat"]<5,5.0,inplace = True)
#since now the income has been set into categories 
#stratified because not even split reprisentative of the population 
split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1,test_size = 0.2,random_state=42)
```

This is loop at the end of the code

```
for train_index,test_index in split.split(housing,housing["income_cat"]):
    strat_train_set = housing.loc[train_index]
    strat_test_set = housing.loc[test_index]
```

Can someone please explain to me what the last for loop is doing? Basically its supposed to be stratifying the data sets into train and test but I am confused especially on the loop header because why is the whole data frame object in the first param then its followed by the income category section. Is it stratifying in reference to each of the income categories created and thus manipulating all the subsequent categories in the whole data frame object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im sure you read already: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.split

So split takes two variables:

*housing*: training data, where n_samples is the number of samples and n_features is the number of features.

*housing["income_cat"]*: The target variable for supervised learning problems. Stratification is done based on the y labels.

and it will return an array of tuples with 2 entries (where each is an ndarray):

First entry: The training set indices for that split.

Second entry: The testing set indices for that split.

Comment: thanks! , up-vote the question if you can just so other's can see this, I was confused on this for like an hour.